# php site w Google Form embedded

Tags: php, google-docs

i have a php site in development wh runs fine.

i have included a google spreadsheet form in it via the iframe tags that Google ask you to copy and paste

the spreadsheet form is obviously there for users to use.

it would be all be so great but I can't see how to get the users id from the parent page into the google form via the iframe

i need this otherwise i won't know who it is who has submitted the form. yes, I cld ask the user to type in their name again but think that's a bit clunky particularly since the info is floating about in the parent page framing the iframe.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a php page which takes the user ID in the query string, then redirects to the correct spreadsheet?  Just set that page as the src of your iframe with the proper user id in the query string, and voila.

Comment: all the php has to be done outside google, I presume. echoing values within a spreadsheet isn't going to permissible. So to me it is not clear how one converts a GET variable into something visible and legible on the Google side. the only answer, wh is low-tech, seems to be to make one's own form using the Google form action. The downside of that is you lose access to Google forms ease of editing, required question option, page breaks, conditional questions etc.

Comment: there is something interesting here about inserting data into a GSS http://farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/ but again what's on offer loses GForms ease-of-use. I just want one little, teeny-tiny thing and that is the user-id added to the GForm data-entry. For the sake of that one little thing, I'd rather not lose GDocs ease-of-use, tho' it appears that I may have no choice.